# Не работает Munin на Debian 8

Tags: linux, веб-программирование, apache, debian

Установил Munin на Debian 8, столкнулся со следующей проблемой. В директории, в которой должны быть файлы Munin (/var/cache/munin/www) ничего нет, папка пустая. Соответственно не могу настроить перенаправление Apache на эту папку.

Как можно решить эту проблему? Кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была связана с тем, что Munin не запускался по крону. поправили в crontab запуск сервиса на эту строчку:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/munin-cron > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Там и не должно ничего быть до тех пор пока мунин не начнёт работать. Пример конфигурации апача находится в /etc/munin/apache24.conf

По идее данный файл должен при установке автоматически линковаться в директорию с конфигурационными настройками apache. Это описано в postinst скрипте мунина. Проверьте /etc/apache24/conf-available/munin.conf - должен на вышеуказанный файл ссылаться.

Comment: Проблема была связана с тем, что Munin не запускался по крону. поправили в crontab запуск сервиса на эту строчку: */5 * * * * /usr/bin/munin-cron > /dev/null 2>&1